# Angular : How to outsource translation on your bucket S3?

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate to manage the translation on my Angular App.
Everything is working well when my files are directly in my application, but I would like to put all my json files on a bucket S3 and use these files for ngx-translate.

I don't know how to change my HttpLoaderFactory function to adapt it to ngx-translate and AWS S3 :

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, translate: TranslateService, ) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'); //URL and S3:// doesn't work here
}
```

I cannot find any information to how to do that on the internet..
If anyone has an answer or an idea to how to do that, I will be happy to test it on my App !

Jb

Comment: What's the error message if you try it with an s3 url? 
Please copy an example of such an url.

Comment: With the S3:// URL I have two errors : FIRST IS `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 's3://elephant-input-dev/public/i18n/fr.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`                                                       
SECOND IS `zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET s3://elephant-input-dev/public/i18n/fr.json net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: You need and url which starts with `http` or `https`, the `s3` protocol is not supported by the browser

Comment: And with the HTTPS URL I have this error `zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET https://elephant-input-dev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/i18n/fr.json 403 (Forbidden)` but I can access this bucket with Amplify and Storage.get() function so I don't understand the forbidden error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting more info through the comments, I'd sum up like:

You have to use a `http` or `https` URL. If you're still getting a `403 Forbidden` error, that means, the resource is not publicly available. From this point this problem is a not an Angular or Typescript related problem, it dependes purely on your server configuration.

Please double check, that you made the resource public on the AWS Admin.

Still, you can get problems with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) even if you made it public. Also check your CORS settings on AWS, if this is the case.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for you information Marcell. And do you know if we need to grant the access for GetObjects or ListObjects in the bucket S3 ?

Comment: GetObjects I guess

Comment: Happy to hear! Don't forget to give my answer an upvote and check your problem solved ;)